# Angular 4 jwt localstorage clear

Tags: angular

I can create JWT localStorage.setItem.

But tried different way to clear it but it does not work.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  [x: string]: any;

  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout() {
    //localStorage.clear();
    //localStorage.reset();
    this.localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

}
```

logout.component.html

```
 <li>
                <a href="#">
                <i class="icon-lock"></i> Lock Screen </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a ng-click="logout()" href="">Log Out</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

here is the screenshot

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Can't understand why down vote without any comment!!!

Comment: it should be this.localStorage.removeItem(...., by guessing that it's an injected service

Comment: Thanks Vega. Yes, this.localStorage.removeItem('currentUser'); is showing error for localStorage

Comment: Yes did this and getting error.

Comment: Then post the class code in whole

Comment: Ok, edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure logout() is called?

Comment: yes did window.localstorage. Yes sure logout() is called. Because the page is navigating to the root

Comment: Please try this: if (localStorage) { 
    console.log("yes!"); 
    localStorage.removeItem("currentUser"); 
    localStorage.clear(); 
} else{
    console.log("no!"); 
}

Comment: Tried this.    let key="currentUser";
    if (key) { console.log('yes!'); return localStorage && localStorage.removeItem(key); } 
    console.log('again yes!'); 
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/admin']);

Comment: It did not work

Comment: what did you get in the log? did you get /admin url?

Comment: No it didnot show anything in log and did not stayed in/admin. It went to root ''/''

Comment: Post how you call logout()

Comment: Yes edited the question.

Comment: this is angular nor angularjs ;) replace ng-click by (click)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Please write answer and I will vote up. Could you please vote up my question also:)

Comment: Next time try to post a minimal but relevant part of your code :)

Comment: Yes Vega. Thanks for your advice. Regards Tanvir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error in your code is confusing Angular's `(click)` event with AngularJS `ng-click`.

So it should be :

```
<a (click)="logout()" href="">Log Out</a>
```

You were misguided by the fact that it was rounting to "/". It was due to the presence of href tag which routes you to "/" anyway.

And you can keep

```
localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
```

Comment: Thanks Vega and also feeling greatful to you

Comment: Yes there is always someone like you :). Also sorry for typo sometime.

Comment: Hello Vega. Just one more thing to inform you <a (click)="logout()" href="#">Log Out</a>. There should be a # in href otherwise it will perform operation. I am writing this if any one read should not copy and paste.

Comment: Yes, # with an id, will link to that id carrying element, # alone, to the top of the page, which is the home, but '' also brings you at the same place

Comment: Yes you are right it will bring the root page. It will create more confusion if the coder just want to route another page except root.